# https doesn't work on Xampp

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

how to make https run on xampp. I'm creating a website but if called with https: // does not work.
i try

```
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/yourProject
ServerName yourProject.whatever
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
```

and

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enBql.png)

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is listening on port 443. Example:

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.foo.com/htdocs

  CustomLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-error.log

  # Example SSL configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/www.foo.com/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/www.foo.com/ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts

Comment: Thank you for your attention. but the above code does not work. the result "404 Page Not Found".

Comment: What kind of application do you use? for example; do you get a response when you go to www.foo.com/index.html? otherwise you can try adding a line like this: DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Comment: I have used the application codeigniter. I tried it "DirectoryIndex index.html index.php", but the result is the same.  the result "404 Page Not Found"